# Object rotates in wrong direction

Tags: transforms

[image]

I wanted to rotate the nut in the picture around its own z-axis. So I turned the transform orientations to *Normal*. But somehow the rotation of this object as well as of the two adjacent obejcts ehaves in a way I don't understand. When I move the object along its normals it behaves the way I would expect.

I also added a new object (the cube in the background) and tried to do the same with it which works well.

If this is of any help: I originaly rotated the object this way by snapping it to another face, afterwards made linked copies and used a mirror modifier. But I can't seem to get behind this issue.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your object has a Delta transform (Rotation X = 90°)

1. Clear rotation in your Delta transforms
2. Add +90° to your regular X Rotation and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>
3. Done.

[image]

Comment: That worked. Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: No problem :). Good luck with your project.